# NiFi Issue: UpdateRecord issue when record has double quotes

Tags: apache-nifi

I am facing one weird issue with UpdateRecord. I am trying to perform operation on below records-

```
id,name,basic                                                                                        
1,"   John Bro   oke  ",34000                                                                            
2, "   John Bro   oke  " ,43678
```

In CSVReader and CSVWriter, Quote Char is set to Single Quote('). In UpdateRecord, we are doing one operation-

[image]

```
/name -> ${field.value:replace('John', "Mark")}
```

The output out of UpdateRecord is as below-

```
1,'   Mark Bro   oke  ',3400                                                                           
2,' "   Mark Bro   oke  " ',43678
```

*If we see the output properly, we will get to know that in first record double quotes are removed for name column. However in input there were double quotes in both the records.*

*The only difference in Input Records is that in first record, name is starting and ending with double quotes but in case of second record, name is starting and ending with one whitespace.*

Not sure how does the space make a difference.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a pretty open-ended format in terms of ways of doing things, but if I had to guess what is happening here is that it's not interpreting the second line's quotes as a "quoted value" because there is white space around them. The normal convention with CSV is to wrap the whole field with quotes and so anything between the delimiter and quote separation character might throw off the reader into not recognizing it as a quoted field value.

Comment: But why this issue is not there if I use Single Quote